Are there any issues with distributing TypeScript sources as the type declarations in a library?
for libraries written in TypeScript, projects normally compile TypeScript sources into JavaScript using tsc and emit declaration files as d.ts files.
// package.json
{
  //...
  "exports": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "default": "./dist/index.js"
  }
}

I am wondering there are any issues with skipping emitting declaration files and pointing the types directly to the project TypeScript sources like so:
// package.json
{
  //...
  "exports": {
    "types": "./src/index.ts",
    "default": "./dist/index.js"
  }
}

For source-available projects, this would allow tsc to be used for type checking only in CI while compilation can be handled using swc.
In the context of a monorepo - this also means not requiring the aliasing of tsconfig#paths to their sources because the IDE sees the sources as the types.
This seems to work in a sandbox, but I am wondering what there are issues with this approach?
For instance, does jsdoc work? Will settings in the library's tsconfig cause conflicts with the consumer package?
